# video to images then images to video in python

Tags: python, video, opencv

I'm trying to convert the following video to images
https://www.signingsavvy.com/media/mp4-ld/24/24851.mp4
however, I have done it by using OpenCV

```
# Importing all necessary libraries 
import cv2 
import os 

# Read the video from specified path 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Users\ahmad\Hi_ASL.mp4")
print(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
try: 

# creating a folder named data 
    if not os.path.exists('data'): 
        os.makedirs('data') 

# if not created then raise error 
except OSError: 
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data') 

# frame 
currentframe = 0

while(True): 

    # reading from frame 
    ret,frame = cam.read() 

    if ret: 
        # if video is still left continue creating images 
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
#         print ('Creating...' + name) 

        # writing the extracted images 
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame) 

        # increasing counter so that it will 
        # show how many frames are created 
        currentframe += 1
    else: 
        break
#     ret,frame = cam.read() 

# Release all space and windows once done 
cam.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After I have done it. I want to convert those images to video to be like the one above and I wrote this code

```
img = [img for img in os.listdir('data')]
frame = cv2.imread('data\' + img[0])
h , w , l = frame.shape
vid = cv2.VideoWriter('hiV.mp4' , 0 ,1 ,(w,h))

for imgg in img:
    vid.write(cv2.imread('data\' + imgg))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vid.release()
```

The problem is the result of combining the images to a video using OpenCV is not the same as the original video. So, what is the problem? I want it to be the same as the original one.
The result of the code above is this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/16vwT35wzc95tBleK5VCpZJQkaLxSiKVd/view?usp=sharing

And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `cv2.VideoWriter('hiV.mp4' , 0 ,1 ,(w,h))` to `cv2.VideoWriter('hiV.mp4' , 0 ,30 ,(w,h))` As the `1` sets the fps and that means that you write 1 frame every second and not 30 or 29.97(NTSC) as the original video.

Comment: Yes, I did that before I post the question but the same. it's not like the original. it's close but no the same. So, I would appreciate it if you have another solution. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Can you send what output you get when you changed the value?

Comment: sure 1 min pls.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QmdIlqz9DPrIn6k-5f9xhcFeYy7dQGsj/view?usp=sharing
Here we go

Comment: I also get that wierd stuttering. I have also tried different codecs but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: After i thought of debugging i found out that it is the way you store the files and how python reads them. A python for loop reads it as followed frame0 = frame 0 frame1=frame 10 and frame10 = 10 and the same goes for frame2 = frame 20 and frame20 = frame 20. While frame01 = frame 1 and  frame02 = frame 2. So you wil either have to look at how you store or read the frame files.

Comment: Hmm, I did not understand you well

Comment: So your for loop reads your frames in the wrong order like this: https://ibb.co/9mDHFmT While when you change the names of the frames that have 1 number to 1 number and a 0 infront like this: 01. Then it reads them in the right order like this: https://ibb.co/mSZ5njq

Comment: yesss I understand what you mean know!! 
Thank you I`ll do that and see what happens